# Finding Angles Given Two Triangles with Equal Perimeters

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

The two right triangles shown below have equal perimeters[image: two right triangles shown]

The hypotenuse of
the orange triangle is one leg of the green triangle stacked on top of it. If the smallest angle of the orange triangle is 20 degrees, what are the angles of the green right triangle?

Comment: @SamWeatherhog The perimeter of the orange triangle is: base + height + sqrt(base^2 + height^2). And the green triangle has the same perimeter. The other angle in the orange triangle is clearly 70deg. I think the answer has something to do with using a trig function to find the hypotenuse of the orange triangle, but I'm not sure in what way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution but it will be difficult to explain. I will use the following variables:

$$
\begin{split} a&=\text{base of orange triangle} \\ b&=\text{height of orange triangle} \\ c&= \text{"left" side of green triangle} \end{split}
$$

Then the hypotenuse of the orange triangle is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and the hypotenuse of the green triangle is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. Since the perimeters of both triangles are equal we must have:

$$
\begin{split} &&a+b=c+\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} \\ &\implies& a+b-c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} \\ &\implies& (a+b-c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2 \\ &\implies& a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab-2ac-2bc=a^2+b^2+c^2 \\ &\implies& ab=ac+bc \\ &\implies& c=\frac{ab}{a+b} \end{split}
$$

So now we have all sides in terms of $a$ and $b$. But we can relate $a$ and $b$ using the angle we are given. So:

$$
\tan(20)=\frac{b}{a} \implies b=a\tan(20)
$$

Using this we get:

$$
\begin{split} a^2+b^2=a^2+a^2\tan^2(20)=a^2(1+\tan^2(20))=\frac{a^2}{\sin^2(20)}  \end{split}
$$

Now we can get an expression for $a^2+b^2+c^2$ purely in terms of $a$:

$$
\begin{split} a^2+b^2+c^2&= \frac{a^2}{\sin^2(20)}+\frac{a^2b^2}{\frac{a^2}{\sin^2(20)}+2ab}\\ &=\frac{a^2}{\sin^2(20)}+\frac{a^4\tan^2(20)}{\frac{a^2}{\sin^2(20)}+2a^2\tan(20)} \\ &=\frac{a^2}{\sin^2(20)}+\frac{a^4\tan^2(20)\sin^2(20)}{a^2+2a^2\tan(20)\sin^2(20)} \\ &=\frac{a^2}{\sin^2(20)}+\frac{a^2\tan^2(20)\sin^2(20)}{1+2\tan(20)\sin^2(20)} \\ &=a^2\left[ \frac{1}{\sin^2(20)}+\frac{\tan^2(20)\sin^2(20)}{1+2\tan(20)\sin^2(20)} \right] \\ &= a^2K^2 \end{split}
$$

where $K^2$ is just the number in the square brackets (the only reason I made it $K^2$ instead of $K$ is because we will need to take square roots). Finally, letting $\theta$ be the smallest angle of the green triangle, we get:

$$
\begin{split} \cos(\theta)&=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \\ &=\frac{\frac{a}{\sin(20)}}{aK} \\ &=\frac{1}{K\sin(20)} \end{split}
$$

You can work out that $K\approx 2.9262$ and then plugging this in gives us $\theta\approx 2.34^{\circ}$.

Comment: Wow that is more complicated than I thought it would be! But it makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It was more complicated than I thought it would be as well! I guess the place to start with these kind of trig problems is to label everything and then start writing down all the relations you can between the things you've labelled. Hopefully you start seeing what labels you can get rid of (e.g. we got rid of the label 'c' by writing it in terms of a and b).

Answer (score -1):

I went through the same process as the previous answer, but discovered a mistake:

$$a^2 + b^2 = a^2 + a^2 \tan^2(20) = a^2 (1 + \tan^2 (20)) = a^2 / \cos^2 (20) \textrm{, not } \sin^2 (20)$$